# How do I find a fix for my runtime int casting error?

Tags: java

So I have a `Prodcut` class that accepts String, String, int, Double (ID, name, quantity, cost).

I also have a `Store` class where I keep all my methods and call them from a console menu. For example, here is my `addProduct` method which gives me an error later on:

```java
Product newProdcut(String id, String prodName, Integer prodQuantity, Double prodCost) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for ( Product p : products ) {
            if ( id.equals(p.id)) {
                System.out.println("Product already exists, please enter the number of the quantity you want to add to the existing quantity:");
                int inputQuantity = sc.nextInt();
                prodQuantity += inputQuantity;
            }
        }
        Product p = new Product(id, prodName, prodQuantity, prodCost);
        this.products.add(p);
        System.out.println("Prodcut "+p.createOutput()+" was added to the list");
        return p;
    }
```

In my menu, I have a method that populates the variables so I'll be able to use them in the menu:

```java
private static ArrayList<String> menuAddProdcut() throws Exception { // 1. Add a prodcut
        Random rand = new Random();
        System.out.println("You're adding a new prodcut");
        ArrayList newProductArray = new ArrayList<>();      
        int prodId = rand.nextInt(1000) + 100;
        String prodIdStr = Integer.toString(prodId); 
        System.out.println("Enter product name:");
        String prodName = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter quantity:");
        Integer prodQuantity = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter product's price:");
        Double price = sc.nextDouble();
        newProductArray.add(prodIdStr); //str-converted ID
        newProductArray.add(prodName);
        newProductArray.add(prodQuantity);
        newProductArray.add(price);

        return newProductArray;         
    }
```

This is how I call the function from the menu:

```java
case 1:
        try {
           ArrayList<String> productToPopulate = Menu.menuAddProdcut();
           int quantity = Integer.parseInt(productToPopulate.get(2));
           Double cost = Double.parseDouble(productToPopulate.get(3));
           st.newProdcut(productToPopulate.get(0), productToPopulate.get(1), quantity, cost);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    break;
```

When I run the program and try to add a product, I get this error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

So I Googled it and found that I should cast it to a String, but I can't because the method accepts str str int double and not 4 str's.

What is my alternative here?

The full error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at Menu.employeeSubMenu(Menu.java:119)
        at Menu.mainMenu(Menu.java:60)
        at Menu.main(Menu.java:25)
```

Comment: In the stack trace should point the line and file where the illegal casting is happening. Could you please share the full error?

Comment: The problem here is that you're using a list to keep heterogeneous data. Why do you think you need to put those values in a list?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Because I'm working with CSV files as well and I need to be able to save and import data from them. It worked well before I started using non String data.

Comment: @PauMAVA added, thanks

Comment: Ok, but if your problem changed you need to change your program as well. Use a class to model a product and convert to string just at the end, when you need to output that data to the CSV file.

Comment: @DanielBeilin Check out line 119 on Menu.java. The problem is there if you want you can share it too.

Comment: @PauMAVA I know, this is the line `int quantity = Integer.parseInt(productToPopulate.get(2));` It's seen in the code I posted. Hence the question about casting

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I will look into that, thanks

Comment: That's somewhat weird. Normally when you cast a String to an int via `Integer.parseInt(s)` it will produce `NumberFormatException` if it cannot be parsed but I have never seen it produce `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by this line:

```
ArrayList newProductArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

You define the variable as the raw type `ArrayList` (raw types are when you don't specify a type argument to a type that needs it). Raw types should be avoided at all cost.

In this case it leads to the `menuAddProdcut` method returning an `ArrayList<String>` that contains objects that are not `String`s! That should not be possible within the full type system and can only happen because raw types break the type system (remember when I told you to avoid them?)

Change the code to

```
ArrayList<String> newProductArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then the compiler will tell you that these lines don't work:

```
newProductArray.add(prodQuantity);
newProductArray.add(price);
```

Because you're trying to add an `Integer` and a `Double` respectively to an `ArrayList<String>`. Change them to something like

```
newProductArray.add(prodQuantity.toString());
newProductArray.add(price.toString());
```

Comment: He also has to change `sc.nextInt()` to `sc.nextLine()`.

Comment: @PauMAVA: no, not necessarily, he might still want to ask the `Scanner` for an int value to ensure the user actually enters a number.

Comment: @JoachimSauer You're a savior! Thank you very very much!